# how can I get an conditional output?

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two integers ( input & output )

```
when input >= 1 and <= 100000 , output will 20
when input >= 100001 and <= 200000 , output will 30
when input >= 200001 and <= 300000 , output will 40
when input >= 300001 and <= 400000 , output will 50
when input >= 400001 and <= 500000 , output will 60
...
...
and so on.
```

Max range of input is unlimited

How can I manage it in C#

Comment: The result you need to get is, essentially, `0 * 10 + 20`, `1 * 10 + 20`, `2 * 10 + 20`, etc. Now think about how you could get the series of `0`, `1`, etc. from the ranges you have.

Comment: Always tag your questions with the appropriate language to ensure they get the maximum audience

Answer (score 1):

```
output = (ceil(input/100000) +1)*10
```

The ceil function basically rounds above a float to an integer.

Comment: You mean `Math.Ceiling()`, not `ceil` (since question was edited to add C# tag). Also you need to put `100000.0` rather than `100000` to avoid integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Simple arithemtic along with integer division should do the trick

```cs
var output = (input / 100000) * 10 + 20;
```

If the `input` is a floating point or decimal already then use `Math.Floor`